# What are the dimensions along which English & Portuguese differ?

Tags: morphology, historical-linguistics, morphosyntax

What are the dimensions along which English & Portuguese differ, and how are these dimensions of variation related and restricted?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I know a good reference.  Roy Major's MA thesis at OSU described the language development of his daughter, Sylvia, as she learned Portuguese and English, and how she came to distinguish the two language systems.  It's [Phonological differentiation of a bilingual child](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1258653953&disposition=inline).